# share image from drawable folder

Tags: java, android

i would like to share a image from drawable folder to Whatsapp.

i tried most of the answer given for this problem in stack overflow but none of them work

```
 String body=textView.getText().toString()+" 

"+"\n"+textViewOne.getText().toString()+" 
"+textViewTwo.getText().toString()+" "+
               textViewThree.getText().toString();

    imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                 + "/drawable/" + "ic_launcher");
         Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
         shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Details");
         shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,body);
         shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
         shareIntent.setType("*/*");
         shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share
      images..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share your assets directly. To achieve what you need you hsve to implement content provider in your app. There are external packages that can simplify that, so you do not need to do that from scratch.